# executing .py in html/php

Tags: python, php, sql, web, execute

I wrote a Python script which writes its output into a txt file.
Then I included that file in my html/php website. - works good so far.
Only remaining problem: I can't execute the .py file automatically while opening the site.
I know that this isn't the best solution
`<?PHP exec("python3 Auswertung.py"); ?>` doesn't seem to work

Comment: Did you try [shell_exec](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.shell-exec.php)?

Comment: Any reason not to write the script in PHP instead?

Comment: What happens when executing `exec("python3 Auswertung.py")`? Likely web user doesn't have permissions to create the file, or execute the python

Comment: I tried shell_exec with the same result. I could‘ve written it in php but I was too lazy actually. Yes, I think the permissions were the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the commands `chown -R www-data:www-data <directory>` and `chmod -R 755 <directory>`. I'm not sure which command solved my problem, but at least its working.